# How do I increase/decrease object size using keyboard in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I do lots of resizing in Illustrator and I would love it if I could decrease and increase object sizes using only keyboard

Are there any shortcuts?

Comment: You can make an action, bind that to a key sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Record and save an action that resizes your object, then set a keyboard shortcut key to that action. For example, you could use the transform panel to scale the object to a specific height, width, or both. You could also use the scale tool to create an action that would scale the selection at your desired %. All of this can be saved as a set of actions and played through shortcut keys.